# Parsing multiple subparsers, but with global arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have read quite a few questions and answers on how to define, parse and run multiple subparsers to run sth like

```
tool.py func_a -a 12 func_b -b 15 input.txt output.txt
                                  ^-- main parser args
                     ^--------------- subparser b
        ^---------------------------- subparser a
```

They usually suggest something like:

```
def func_a(args):
    pass

def func_b(args):
    pass


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# Define subparsers
subp_a = subparsers.add_parser(func_a.__name__)
subp_a.set_defaults(func=func_a)
subp_a.add_argument('-a')

subp_b = subparsers.add_parser(func_b.__name__)
subp_b.set_defaults(func=func_b)
subp_b.add_argument('-b')

# Define global parameters
parser.add_argument('input', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('output', type=argparse.FileType('wb', 0))

# Parse and run through all arguments
rest = sys.argv[1:]
while rest:
    args, rest = parser.parse_known_args(rest)
    args.func(args)
```

However this implementation has one problem: The arguments `input` and `output` are defined for the main parser and should only be used once. However, each call of `parser.parse_known_args(rest)` expects the values to be set and consequently removes it from `rest`.

This means the first call to `parse_known_args` retrieves the values and each subsequent call fails due to missing arguments.

Is there a solution to overcome this without manually copying the values into the `rest` list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first `parse_known_args` consumes the filenames along with the 1st subparser level.

You could define 2 parsers, one with the 'global' positionals, one without.  First parse with the 'with' parser, hanging onto its `args` (for the filenames).  Then work your way down the subparser stack with the 'without' parser.

Here's a simpler example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo')
subp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
cmd1 = subp.add_parser('cmd1')
cmd1.add_argument('-a')
cmd2 = subp.add_parser('cmd2')
# parser.add_argument('bar')  # confusing location

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subp = parser1.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
cmd1 = subp.add_parser('cmd1', parents=[cmd1], add_help=False)
cmd2 = subp.add_parser('cmd2')

# Parse and run through all arguments
args, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
print args, rest
while rest:
    args, rest = parser1.parse_known_args(rest)
    print args, rest
```

I put the `parser` `foo` before `subp` because it creates less confusion there.  A positional at the end (`bar`) may be confused with arguments for one of the subparsers, or one of the nested subparsers - especially when generating error messages.

To get an idea of how `parse_args` will allocate argument strings to the various positionals, try a script like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo')
parser.add_argument('cmd', nargs=argparse.PARSER, choices=['cmd1','cmd2']) 
parser.add_argument('bar') 
print parser.parse_args()
```

To `parser`, the subparsers argument looks just a like a positional that takes at least one string (kind of like `'+'`), and the 1st must match `choices`.  It will receive all the 'remaining' strings, consistent with the demands of the other positionals.